# Using a lex program to analyze an asm file

Tags: assembly, lex, analyzer

I am using this lex program to analyze the usage of each register, whether they are used as a source, a destination, or used as an indirect addressing, these are my codes, i have to analyze all 12 registers...is there any other efficient way to do these as oppose to declaring 36 variables, and 36 rules? (I am a student).

```
%{ 
#include <stdio.h>

int q,w,e,r,t,y,u,i,o,p,a,s = 0;

%}

%%
[push|dec]?+[ ]+(eax|EAX)+[,] q++ ;
[,| ]+(eax|EAX)+[ ]? w++ ;
['[']+(eax|EAX)+[ ]? e++ ;
[push|dec]?+[ ]+(ebx|EBX)+[,] r++ ;
[,| ]+(ebx|EBX)+[ ]? t++ ;
['[']+(ebx|EBX)+[ ]? y++ ;
[push|dec]?+[ ]+(ecx|ECX)+[,] u++ ;
[,| ]+(ecx|ECX)+[ ]? i++ ;
['[']+(ecx|ECX)+[ ]? o++ ;
[push|dec]?+[ ]+(edx|EDX)+[,] p++ ;
[,| ]+(edx|EDX)+[ ]? a++ ;
['[']+(edx|EDX)+[ ]? s++ ;




. ;



%%

main()

{

yylex() ;

printf("EAX as source: %d\n", q) ;
printf("EAX as destination: %d\n", w) ;
printf("EAX as indirect address: %d\n", e) ;
printf("EBX as source: %d\n", r) ;
printf("EBX as destination: %d\n", t) ;
printf("EBX as indirect address: %d\n", y) ;
printf("ECX as source: %d\n", u) ;
printf("ECX as destination: %d\n", i) ;
printf("ECX as indirect address: %d\n", o) ;
printf("EDX as source: %d\n", p) ;
printf("EDX as destination: %d\n", a) ;
printf("EDX as indirect address: %d\n", s) ;
}
```

this is my output:

```
EAX as source: 56
EAX as destination: 71
EAX as indirect address: 0
EBX as source: 25
EBX as destination: 38
EBX as indirect address: 0
ECX as source: 26
ECX as destination: 30
ECX as indirect address: 0
EDX as source: 30
EDX as destination: 38
EDX as indirect address: 0
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ^C
```

the file i am trying to analyze is here [this is where the asm file is](http://www.cefns.nau.edu/~ap27/cs200/files/Along32.asm)

Comment: Seems like you could define `Register` as one of `EAX, EBX, ECX`, etc., and then replace the specific register names in your expressions with `Register`. So you'd have just one set of expressions. It's been too long since I used lex, though, so I don't remember how that's done.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in my comment, it's been a long time since I worked with lex. The idea, though, is to define your registers and then an expression that uses that definition.

So, for example, your lex file would be something like:

```
%

R EAX|eax|EBX|ebx|ECX|ecx|EDX|edx

%%

[push|dec]?+[ ]+({R})+[,] q++ ;
[,| ]+({R})+[ ]? w++ ;
['[']+({R})+[ ]? e++ ;

%%

main()
...
```

My syntax probably isn't perfect, but that's the general idea. Look up some simple lex definition examples.